# Ejecutar funciones una a continuación de otra

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Como se llama esta técnica para invocar una función a continuación de otra y dónde existen ejemplos:

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Comment: `Como se llama esta técnica para invocar una función a continuación de otra` Chaining methods. `y dónde existen ejemplos`  internet, cosa de colocar en el buscador de tu agrado: "chaining methods C#" y a leer. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente se le conoce como **Encadenamiento de métodos**, *Methods chaining* en inglés, y es la técnica que se utiliza al crear APIs con **Interfaz Fluida**, *Fluent API* en inglés. Es una manera cómoda y efectiva de pasar el contexto de ejecución entre una llamada y la siguiente para simplificar el código y aumentar la productividad, eso según algunos, o una forma de oscurecer el código y de disminuir su flexibilidad, según otros.